# How can I make an existing mesh appear to be drawn in animation?

Tags: animation

I have a mesh of a football field that I want to render so that it seems to be drawn onto another plane in an animation. The basic idea, in the end, is that I want to make an animation that shows a football field being created on a barren piece of land, but I first want to figure out how to do this first step of drawing the lines.

Here's my mesh:[image: football field]

I'd like for it to either start smack in the middle or on one of the corners, from nothing to the mesh here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animate the size of another object (*e.g.* the radius of a cylinder) using keyframes, and then apply a boolean *intersect* modifier to your mesh.

[image]

### Step by step

1. Create a cylinder with the middle in the point where you want the "drawing" to start. Make sure that it's thick enough to cover all the mesh on the *Z* direction

   [image]
   [image]
2. Scale it down on the *X* and *Y* directions hitting <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>

   [image]
3. Set a keyframe to the current size using <kbd>I</kbd> > *Scaling*. Then move to the end frame, scale it up (again only along *X-Y* with <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), and set another keyframe (<kbd>I</kbd> > *Scaling*).

   [image]
4. Optionally, you can avoid the visualization of a solid cylinder by setting its *maximum draw type* to *wire*

   [image]
5. Last, select your mesh and add a *Boolean* modifier, using the *Intersect* method and your cylinder as the reference object

   [image]

Comment: Ah, thank you, that's very helpful! I think I understand.

Comment: I've added a step-by-step tutorial. Hope it helps.